# Makefile with selection

Tags: make

I am using the following makefile to run the command

```
texi2pdf 06a-amcoh.texi
```

But I also have two other files, namely `06a-amcoh-igm.texi` and `06a-amcoh-rfc.texi`, which I also want to be able to call `texi2pdf 06a-amcoh-igm.texi` and `texi2pdf 06a-amcoh-rfc.texi`.

How may I modify the `makefile` to be able to call `texi2pdf` for the specific files.

```
.PHONY: all new again clean

ch6 := $(wildcard *amcoh.texi)
igm := $(wildcard *igm.texi)
rfc := $(wildcard *rfc.texi)

pdfs := $(tfiles:.texi=.pdf)

all: ${pdfs}

%.pdf: %.texi
    texi2pdf $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f ${pdfs}

again:
    ${MAKE} clean
    ${MAKE}

new:
    ${MAKE} again
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to  include their names in the `pdfs` list.

But the idiomatic way to do it is to start from source (in your case the .texi files) and from them, dynamically generate the output list (in your case .pdf files)

Also, you  should mark the targets as `.PHONY` for which no corresponding file exists.

```
.PHONY: all new again clean ch6 igm rf 

ch6 := $(wildcard *amcoh.texi)
igm := $(wildcard *igm.texi)
rfc := $(wildcard *rfc.texi)

tfiles := $(ch6) $(igm) $(rfc)
pdfs := $(tfiles:.texi=.pdf)

define mkRule
$(eval $1: $$(filter $$($1:.texi=.pdf),$$(pdfs)))
endef
$(call mkRule,ch6)
$(call mkRule,igm)
$(call mkRule,rfc)

all: ${pdfs}

%.pdf: %.texi
    texi2pdf $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f ${pdfs}

again:
    ${MAKE} clean
    ${MAKE} all

new:
    ${MAKE} again
```

Now invoke make as :

```
make igm    #to process *igm.texi
```

Comment: One difficulty is that I do not want to run texi2pdf automatically on all files.  But, rather, I want to instruct make which file to use,

Comment: Then list them out individually in that case. My answer is edited to reflect that

Comment: Thanks.  Still I find a problem because I have to modify the makefile everytime I want to run texi2pdf on a different file.

Comment: If you don't want to touch the Makefile, then supply the .texi files to make from the command line in that case.

Comment: Would need different strings that I can pass to make, so it will run the command on the appropriate file. Would need to pass something to the command line as you say.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: And if I do just "make" it will do texi2pdf on all files matching wildcard.

Comment: Yes, you got the hang of it now.

Comment: Could I have an easier way such as "make rfc" that handles "*rfc.texi" files?

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
pdfs := 06a-amcoh.pdf
```

to

```
pdfs := 06a-amcoh.pdf 06a-amcoh-igm.pdf 06a-amcoh-rfc.pdf
```